# Is there a way to show values which are generated for quickCheck and quickBatch

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I run quickBatch tests for this code:

```
data List a = 
    Nil 
  | Cons a (List a) 
  deriving (Eq, Show) 

instance Functor List where
  fmap _ Nil         = Nil
  fmap f (Cons a as) = Cons (f a) (fmap f as)

instance Applicative List where
  pure a = Cons a Nil
  Nil <*> _ = Nil
  _ <*> Nil = Nil
  (Cons f fs) <*> as = fmap f as `append` (fs <*> as)

append :: List a -> List a -> List a
append Nil ys         = ys
append (Cons x xs) ys = Cons x $ xs `append` ys

instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (List a) where
  arbitrary = frequency [(1, return Nil), (2, Cons <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary)]

main :: IO ()
main =
  hspec $ do
    describe "List" $ do
      it "Functor" $
        property (quickBatch $ functor (undefined :: List (Int, Float, String)))
      it "Applicative" $
        property (quickBatch $ applicative (undefined :: List (Int, Float, String)))
```

When the weights for Arbitrary are 1 and 2, all tests together require 5 sec to finish. But when I make the weights 1 and 499 (Nil is taken once and actual values are taken 499 times, is it correct?), all tests are slower, especially each applicative composition test requires like 5 minutes. So I wonder where does this behavior come from, and maybe I could see generated values somehow.

Comment: Well it is one in 500 change that the list terminates in that case.

Comment: I see... So there is some kind of loop inside Arbitrary, but I don't understand how it works

Comment: the second `arbitrary` in your `Cons <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary` is a recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can calculate the probability distribution of a list having *n* elements. If you implement it:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (List a) where
    arbitrary = frequency [(1, return Nil), (k, Cons <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary)]
```

then there is *1/(1+k)* that the list terminates. Note that the `arbitrary` in boldface, is a the arbitrary you define here, you thus make a *recursive* call. It thus means that the likelihood for a list having length *n* is:

*P(|L|=n) = k<sup>n-1</sup>/(1+k)<sup>n</sup>*

This is a [*Gemetrical distribution* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), and the average length of the list will be *k* (the average of the variable of the Geometrical distribution is *k+1*, but that *includes* the `Nil` element). So that means that if you set *k* to `499`, you will on average generate a list of 499 elements, whereas if you set `k` to `2`, it generates lists of on average a length of 2. Of course the computational effort scales in the length of the list.